# Reinstall linux without losing data

Tags: partition, system-installation, elementary-os

Yesterday my laptop wouldn't boot (elementary os).
I used fsck and it got worse and the distro was completely corrupted. So I want to reinstall the distro without losing my data
and I've searched on the internet and found many solutions but because I'm new to Linux I couldn't risk with my data. I downloaded EOS 5.1 (mine 5.0). I got stuck on this screen and don't know what to do to keep my home directory safe after installing.

Note:

sda1 is where the current OS is installed.
sda5 contains my files in the username folder.

[image: EOS installer]

Comment: Your have one root partition which contains `/home` and every other directory and file on your system except for the swap space. If you reinstall the operating system, it's going to remove everything. The only way to keep the data is to boot from a live USB and copy the data to an external drive. In the future, use logical volumes and create a separate one for the data that you want to keep in case of failure.

Comment: my files are in sda5 and the distro files are in sda1 so can i avoid earsing all data on sda5 and install it on sda1

Comment: Yes you can. You need to tell the installer to NOT add a new file-system, for the home partition, and set its mount point to `/home`. I have done it for debian, and every system that I update. But I can't give step my step instruction: it may vary my distro, and I can't remember.

Comment: You said that you wanted to keep your home directory safe which led me to believe that the files were in there. If they are in /dev/sda5, then reinstalling the operating system won't affect then but 1) it will still wipe out the data in /home and 2) if the disk itself is corrupted, then reinstalling the operating system isn't going to help because there's a chance that some if the data is also corrupted and that the disk is going to fail.

Comment: If I am still mistaken and `/dev/sda5` is mounted at `/home`, then you can reinstall the OS to `/dev/sda1`. It's still better to replace the failing disk altogether and start backing up your data.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes that what i need but i can't do because i'm beginner with linux 
what exactly should I do ? 
format sda1 and mount it to what / or /home ? and the other sda(s) what should i do with them ?

Comment: @NasirRiley sorry for misunderstanding because i'm not familiar with linux , and so I couldn't explain my problem clearly .
and yes you are right but i can't install it on sda1 could you tell me how ?

Comment: from what you say, and the image in the question `/dev/sda1` should have a new file-system created on it (formatting is a different thing, and rarely needed any more. Microsoft confuses the two concepts; you won't see an option to format, you will see create file-system. It looks like `/dev/sda5` may be home, and should me mounted on `/home`. And **must not** be re-created.

Comment: I see that the home partition is about 65G, so why not get an external device to back it up to.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor home directory files aren't very important to copy them to external device , and sorry for wasting your time with me but last thing i don't know exactly how to install the new distro without using new partition table ( i need to keep the currnet partitions as they are like installing new microsoft windows)  could you tell me exactly what the steps to install it on sda1? and thanks for your time

Comment: Is this the same question?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor thanks i was able to do it can you put your comment in answer so i can give you best answer ?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you had your `/home` in a partition of its own, you WILL lose your data if you reinstall.

Use a live-distro of your choice, start your laptop from that and see if you can copy your home-directory to an external disk.

The OS-Version you want to install differs from the version you had installed previously. This will most likely cause problems with configuration-files in your home-dir.  I would strongly recommend that you backup your /home-partition first.

Use a live-distro of your choice, start your laptop from that and see if you can copy your home-directory to an external disk.

AFTER you have made a backup, do a fresh install.

- Install the system to `/dev/sda1`, with mountpoint `/` as shown on your screenshot.
- Select mountpoint `/home` for `/dev/sda5` and DO format the drive.
- After the install is finished, copy back your files from your backup to your new home.  But only those that are not config-files.  Those need to be checked carefully to make sure their structure/syntax is still the same.

As an alternative, download the OS-Version you had installed previously and do NOT format `/dev/sda5`.  Backups still strongly recommended.

Comment: I have my files on sda5 and i need to install the distro on sda1 which have the files of current distro

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You need to tell the installer to NOT add a new file-system, for the home partition, and set its mount point to `/home`. I have done it for debian, and every system that I update.

From what you say, and the image in the question `/dev/sda1` should have a new file-system created on it (formatting is a different thing, and rarely needed any more. Microsoft confuses the two concepts; you won't see an option to format, you will see create file-system. It looks like `/dev/sda5` may be home, and should me mounted on `/home`. And must not be re-created.